# Simple retrofit2 request to a localhost server

Tags: java, android, tomcat, retrofit2, nosql

trying to make an android app that will communicate with a localhost server (tomcat apache) which use noSQL server (app->tomcat->noSQL). I already manage to make a servlet that handle params on "get" method and load them correctly to the database, now I am trying to insert the data from my app using retrofit2 lib.
following vids and tutorials I still couldnt manage to make this work.

this is the interface I am using:

```
public interface APIService {

    @POST("login")
    Call<Boolean> postUser(@Body User user);

    @GET("login")
    Call<Boolean> getUser(@Query("user_email") String user_email,@Query("user_pass") String user_pass);

    public static final Retrofit retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
            .baseUrl("http://localhost:8080/")
            .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
            .build();
}
```

and this is the code I am using when the button is clicked in the app:

```
APIService ApiService = APIService.retrofit.create(APIService.class);

User user = new User(name, email);
Call<Boolean> call = ApiService.getUser(email,name);
call.enqueue(new Callback<Boolean>() {
    @Override
    public void onResponse(Call<Boolean> call, Response<Boolean> response) {
        String ans = response.message(); //for debugging
        if (ans.compareTo("yes") == 0) {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "YES!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        } else if (ans.compareTo("no") == 0) {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "NO!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        } else {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "ELSE?!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onFailure(Call<Boolean> call, Throwable t) {
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), t.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }



});
```

so atm, nothing happen when I am clicking the button.(it used to crush but it stopped) and I am sure the the button's function is being called.

Answer (score 17):

If you are using emulator, then change URL to `http://10.0.2.2:8080/`.

Comment: The app is installed on my phone

Comment: Then use IP address of your PC

Comment: What about server installed on phone? It should be localhost, but it doesn't work

Answer (score 3):

Two ways your problem can solved

1. If u are running with emulator use URL as http://10.0.2.2:8080/
   instead of localhost
2. Running from mobile app use PC IP address