# How to call localhost from retrofit2?

Tags: android, retrofit2

I am trying to access an API on localhost(127.0.0.1) from my android emulator. I have a breakpoint on the API.

1. Postman calls the API with no issues.
2. Google Chrome on the emulator calls the API with no issues.
3. My app on the emulator can call APIs if I change the URL to something on the internet such as "https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com"
4. My app on the android emulator is not able to call the API on localhost(127.0.0.1). It doesn't activate the breakpoint on the API action.

The retrofit code:

```
public class TestApiContainer {

    public interface TestApi {

        @GET("EmptyTest/test")
        Call<String> test();
    }

    static TestApi testApi;

    public static TestApi api(){
        if (testApi == null)
            testApi = new Retrofit
                    .Builder()
                    .baseUrl("https://10.0.2.2:44351")
                    .addConverterFactory(ScalarsConverterFactory.create())
                    .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
                    .build()
                    .create(TestApi.class);
        return testApi;
    }
}
```

Calling code:

```
TestApiContainer.api().test().enqueue(new Callback<String>() {
    @Override
    public void onResponse(Call<String> call, Response<String> response) {
        
        if (!response.isSuccessful())
            return;
    }
});
```

Postman screenshot:
[image]

It also works on the Android emulator's Google Chrome. Screenshot:
[image]

What might be wrong with my setup? Could you please help.

Comment: This [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40077927/simple-retrofit2-request-to-a-localhost-server) may be helpful. Lmk

Comment: It wasn't helpful. If it was, I wouldn't have asked this question in the first place. I am already using 10.0.2.2 instead of localhost.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're probably getting a certificate error, since you're requesting HTTPS, but your chrome screenshot's warning symbol indicates a possible SSL issue.

Try:

1. Changing your base URL to `http://10.0.2.2:44351`.
2. [Permitting cleartext traffic for that IP](https://medium.com/mindorks/my-network-requests-are-not-working-in-android-pie-7c7a31e33330).

If this doesn't help, you should update your question with the logcat errors you are seeing.