# Erreur Retrofit Get

Tags: android, retrofit, okhttp, hostname

I cannot recover the data from my Wordpress API with the Retrofit library.
The error is :
HTTP FAILED: java.net.UnknownHostException: Unable to resolve host "app.divion.fr": No address associated with hostname

ApiClient :

```
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;
import retrofit2.Call;
import kotlin.contracts.Returns;
import okhttp3.OkHttpClient;
import okhttp3.logging.HttpLoggingInterceptor;
import retrofit2.Retrofit;
import retrofit2.converter.gson.GsonConverterFactory;

public class ApiClient extends AppCompatActivity {

//Adresse de l'Api

public static final String BASE_URL = "https://app.divion.fr/wp-json/api/";

//Retrofit Api Client

private static Retrofit retrofit = null;

public static Retrofit getApiClient(){
    HttpLoggingInterceptor loggingInterceptor = new HttpLoggingInterceptor();
    loggingInterceptor.level(HttpLoggingInterceptor.Level.BODY);
    OkHttpClient client = new OkHttpClient.Builder()
                                .addInterceptor(loggingInterceptor)
                                .build();
    if (retrofit == null){

        retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
                .baseUrl(BASE_URL)
                .client(client)
                .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
                .build();
    }
    return retrofit;
}
```

}

ApiInterface :

```
package com.example.allomairie.rest;

import java.util.Map;

import retrofit2.Call;
import retrofit2.http.GET;
import retrofit2.http.QueryMap;
```

public interface ApiInterface {

```
// Retrofit Interface
//JSON --> GSON Library --> Java Object


@GET("homepage_api")
Call<Object> getHomepageApi(@QueryMap Map<String, String> params);
```

}

Manifest.xml

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```

```
<!-- Ajout de la permission internet pour les actualités worpdress -->
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
<!-- if you want to load images from a file OR from the internet -->
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/Theme.AlloMairie">
    <activity android:name=".MainActivity">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
</application>
```

Thx ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like DNS server cannot recognize the Url you specified. Are you sure https://app.divion.fr/wp-json/api/ is an actual working url?
You can copy and paste the url in a web browser and see if it opens a page to verify. If it is not a valid Url, please use a valid one.

Comment: Hello thx for your response, i test in localhost.

Comment: If you're testing in localhost then you must use localhost base url, see https://stackoverflow.com/a/56593354/4704327