# retrofit onFailure() keeps triggering on connecting to localhost

Tags: java, android, xampp, retrofit

I want to connect to my localhost server for testing my app. For this reason, I am using the `retrofit` library. This is my interface class, which defines the url to connect to:

```
import retrofit2.Call;
import retrofit2.http.Field;
import retrofit2.http.FormUrlEncoded;
import retrofit2.http.POST;

public interface PostInterface {

    String JSONURL = "http://80.0.0.13/";
    @FormUrlEncoded
    @POST("login_screen/backend.php")
    Call<String>  getUserLogin(
        @Field("input") String input,
        @Field("username") String uname,
        @Field("password") String password
    );
}
```

I am calling this interface in my java code:

```
    Call<String> call = null;
    Retrofit retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
            .baseUrl(PostInterface.JSONURL)
            .addConverterFactory(ScalarsConverterFactory.create())
            .build();

    PostInterface api = retrofit.create(PostInterface.class);

    call = api.getUserLogin("sign in", "abc", "abc@xyz");

     if (call != null) {
        call.enqueue(new Callback<String>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(Call<String> call, Response<String> response) {
                if (response.body() != null) {
                    Log.d("success",response.body());
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void onFailure(Call<String> call, Throwable t) {
                Snackbar snackbar = Snackbar.make(findViewById(android.R.id.content), t.toString(), Snackbar.LENGTH_SHORT);
                snackbar.show();
            }
        });
     }
```

Strangely, the `onFailure()` method keeps triggering everytime with the following throwable:

> javaSocketTimeoutException: Failed to connect to /80.0.0.13 (port 80)....

But when I try the url in my android browser or pc browser, it works fine.

Things I have checked:

1. The project is stored inside `C:\xampp\htdocs`, having the exact same hierarchy as in my live server location.
2. Both `Apache` and `SQL` ports are open in my `xampp` control panel.
3. My localhost port number is default **80**
4. When I run the app in my emulator using this ip `http://10.0.2.2:80/`, then it works fine

Why is the app failing to connect to my local server?

**EDIT**: I can access my site from my phone browser using my pc ip address, but when I want to access it from the app, then the `onFailure()` triggers

Comment: Does this help?: https://stackoverflow.com/a/40078016/9715339

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/21801176/115145

Comment: As, the post suggested, I used my ip address. The`onFailure()` still keeps on triggering

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After much struggling, I finally found the solution from a post in github:

1. **Turn on USB Tethering & USB Debugging Mode in your mobile.**
2. **Connect your mobile to your laptop/desktop through USB.**
3. **Now just change the ip address (run "ipconfig" in cmd)**

Answer (score -2):

This is because `localhost` is not a valid URL for android.

The `localhost` is a loopback address, which means that the network request will be handled by current device by some application (PHP server).

So, when you enter `localhost` on your machine (PC/laptop), it will check for server application listening at specified port (in your case 80) and will forward that request to the server application. In your case it is XAMPP which is listening at port `80`.

But, when you goto an Android application, there is no server application **running on android device or emulator** since they are different device. Hence you get 404 error for localhost on Android.

To fix this, simply get the IP address of your PC (using `ipconfig` command) and use that instead of localhost.

E.g.: In cas the IP address is `192.168.0.129`, then your URL would be `http://192.168.0.129:80/`

Comment: I tried using my ip address. My ip address is `80.0.0.13`, so I changed the url to `https://80.0.0.13:80/`, but it's still not working

Comment: Are both devices are on same network? i.e. connected to same wifi?

Comment: Yes both my pc and mobile are connected to the same wifi